# Programmatically Check Color Contrast C#

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

I'm trying to get the background and the foreground color of my app based on an image. (just like how iTunes uses the songs album cover) but I am having problem getting the perfect color combination where in some cases I get two colors that is too neon or too light to be background and two colors that is nearly the same color which is not what I am trying to achieve.

If anyone knows how iTunes algorithm works this would be perfect.

as of now. this is the code i'm using but it's not perfect.

```
Dim Image As FileStream = New FileStream(Path.Combine(dir, "GetColor.jpg"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)

            Using bmp = New Bitmap(Image)
                For x = 2 To bmp.Width - 2
                    For y = 2 To bmp.Height - 2
                        If colorList.ContainsKey(bmp.GetPixel(x, y)) Then colorList(bmp.GetPixel(x, y)) += 1 Else colorList.Add(bmp.GetPixel(x, y), 1)
                    Next
                Next
                bmp.Dispose()
            End Using
            Image.Close() : Image.Dispose()

            Dim colors = colorList.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.Value)
            accent(0) = colors(0).Key : accent(1) = Nothing

            For Each a In colors
                Dim z() As Integer = {a.Key.R, a.Key.G, a.Key.B}
                If Math.Abs(z(0) - accent(0).R) > 100 Xor Math.Abs(z(1) - accent(0).G) > 100 Xor Math.Abs(z(2) - accent(0).B) > 100 Then
                    Select Case accent(0).GetBrightness < 0.5
                        Case True
                            If Math.Abs(a.Key.GetBrightness - accent(0).GetBrightness) > 0.25 Then
                                If a.Key.GetBrightness > 0.25 Then
                                    accent(1) = a.Key
                                    Exit For
                                End If
                            End If
                        Case False
                            If a.Key.GetBrightness < accent(0).GetBrightness Then
                                If accent(0).GetBrightness < 0.75 AndAlso a.Key.GetBrightness < 0.45 Or a.Key.GetBrightness < 0.5 AndAlso Math.Abs(a.Key.GetBrightness - accent(0).GetBrightness) > 0.4 AndAlso a.Key.GetSaturation < 0.75 Then
                                    accent(1) = a.Key
                                    Exit For
                                End If
                            End If
                    End Select
                End If
            Next
            If accent(1) = Nothing Then
                Select Case accent(0).GetBrightness < 0.35
                    Case True : accent(1) = Color.White
                    Case False : accent(1) = Color.FromArgb(255, accent(0).R * 0.075, accent(0).G * 0.075, accent(0).B * 0.075)
                End Select
            End If
            If accent(0).GetBrightness > accent(1).GetBrightness Then
                accent(2) = accent(0) : accent(0) = accent(1) : accent(1) = accent(2)
            End If
            accent(2) = accent(0) : accent(3) = accent(0)
            colorList = Nothing
            colors = Nothing
        End If
```

I would love to check your suggestions to improve my work. so far. this is how it works.

- first i resize the image to 30x30
- then i get the color of all the pixels and sort it by count.
- i automatically use the dominant color as the first color.
- then in this part. i don't know what i'm doing but it's working perfectly in most cases.
- then compare the brightness of two colors, and switch them if color1 is brighter than color2
- in this part, if i didn't find a second color, which is this is exactly my problem, how come i can't find a second color. i use either black or white depending on the GetBrightness function.

i would love to see your ideas. or any related links that could help me.

Comment: Why have you tagged ios and itunes here? Those tags are for specific ios and itunes related questions.

Comment: i perfectly stated that i am trying to achieve how iTunes color grabbing on artwork algorithm works.

Comment: You did and that would have been enough. Absolutely no need to tag ios and itunes as this problem is not about ios or itunes. Tags are used to help people search specific type of questions. ios and itunes are for people who are looking for questions about ios and itunes.